# how to convert a date column with varchar datatype to another date format

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a date column with datatype 'nvarchar(50)' and it is displayed as '01/08/2012', '02/08/2012', etc. in the original table

But I want it to be displayed as '20120801', '20120802' in a query or stored procedure and parameter in stored procedure should also be able to put as '20120801', '20120802'

I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Create procedure testprocedure 
@startdate nvarchar(8), @enddate nvarchar(8)
As
Begin
select convert(varchar(8),date,112) AS DATE, field1, field2 from tbltable
where date between @startdate and @enddate
End
Go

execute testprocedure @startdate = '20120801', @enddate = '20120805'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you declare `@enddate` and `@startdate` as `datetime` sql variables?

Comment: If it's a date - why aren't you **storing** it as a `DATE` or `DATETIME` ? That would make your task just so much easier! Also: `DATE` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server 2008 - you shouldn't call your column `date` - that'll just cause confusion and errors

Comment: thanks for the tips...actually i import data from csv and by default sql server takes the date column of csv in varchar(50) datatype in sql server table. I tried changing it to datetime several times but somehow i was getting error and I was not able to import the data into it. So I just left it as nvarchar(50)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is : date is nvarchar you should convert it to Date then convert it to other format.

```
select convert(varchar(8),CAST(tdate as Date),112) AS DATE, field1, field2 from tbltable
```

tdate is tbltable.tdate.

it works.

Comment: Is tdate a function or a typo here?

Comment: tdate is "date". i changeed it to tdate because date is keword in sql server.

Comment: I get error `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime`
I replaced cast(tdate as Date) to (tdate as Datetime) because i was getting error date is not valid datatype...